# Magento 2.4 - In-Store Pickup - always display one store at the top of the list - or show alphabetically not by distance

Tags: magento2.4, store-pickup

We are using the in-Store Pickup locator that is inbuilt to Magento 2.4

Can the in-store pickup list have 1 store location always displayed at the top?

Basically, we are using in-store pickup but with 1 brick and mortar store location plus 20 or so School locations that we deliver to - therefore the customer needs to pick the school that they go to - which is generally not always the nearest OR the store itself.

Currently, the store always appears mid-list and we are concerned customers will miss it

So hoping that there is a way to always display the store at the start of the list either before or after the "selected" store/school - even if it's repeated and also displayed in the list below as well?

Any ideas if this is possible?

Another way possibly of doing it is switching off the distance aspect and so the list would display alphabetically and naturally our store would appear first - but can imagine that is tougher being that the store locator is based upon distance!

Added [screenshot](https://demowebsq.co.uk/m2-ac-122021.jpg) of what we have to help - any ideas or thoughts very very welcome!

[image]

Thank you
Sarah

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Source Priority` algorithm instead of `Distance Priority`. 
Check https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-configure-source-priority.html for reference

Comment: Thank you! - we already have SOURCE PRIORITY created with our main store at the top BUT how do I change where you set the algorithm to say you only want to use SOURCE and not DISTANCE?